# Prove $ \int _0^1\:e^xf\left(1-x\right)dx=\int _0^1\:e^x\left(f′\left(1-x\right)\right)dx$.

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm having trouble with following problem, thinking about integration by parts but just getting circular answer:

> Let $f$ by continuous on $[0,1]$ and differentiable on $(0,1)$, and also $f(0)=f(1)=0$. Prove
>   $$ \int _0^1\:e^xf\left(1-x\right)=\int _0^1\:e^x\left(f′\left(1-x\right)\right)$$

Comment: Note that when you do $(f(1-x))' = -f'(1-x)$ where the minus sign is due to the derivative of $1-x$. When you integrate the LHS by parts, you have a term which is null because of the condition $f(0)=f(1)=0$, namely $e^x f(1-x) |_{0}^{1}$. Then the answer follows.

Comment: Very polite title but I wonder if it can be shortened? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(1-x)=u$ and $e^xdx=dv$ then $f'(1-x)\times-1dx=du$ and $e^x=v$, with integration by parts

> $$\int udv=uv-\int v du$$

we have

> \begin{align}
> \int _0^1\:e^xf\left(1-x\right)dx
> &= f(1-x)e^x|_0^1-\int _0^1e^xf'(1-x)\times-1dx \\
> &= f(0)e^1-f(1)e^0+\int _0^1e^xf'(1-x)dx \\
> &= \int _0^1e^xf'(1-x)dx
> \end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Using integration by parts and exploiting of the fact $f(0)= f(1)=0$, it all boils down to $$\int_0^1 e^x f(1-x) \mathrm{d}x = -\int_0^1 e^x \Big(f(1-x)\Big)' \mathrm{d}x+ [e^x f(1-x)]_{0}^1 = \int_0^1 e^x f'(1-x) \mathrm{d}x $$ as desired, after some caution with the argument of the $f$ function and a chain rule application, as $(1-x)' = -1$.